# jqgrid - how to center delete action icon

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I don't know how to center delete action icon in inline editing.

[image: screen]

**My setting action column is:**

```
{
    name: 'action',
    width: 40,
    align: "center",
    editable: false,
    formatter:'actions',
    search: false,
    fixed: true,
    resize: false,
    formatoptions: { keys: true, editbutton: false }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play around with CSS to find the fix in your case. Try overriding jqGrid's CSS rules.

In general, if you have only 'Delete' icon in your column, following CSS rules will make it center aligned.

```
.ui-pg-div.ui-inline-del {
  float: none !important;
}

span.ui-icon.ui-icon-trash {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Although, its not a good practice to use '!important'.

If you want to do this for a particular grid, you can prepend grid id(say, list) to CSS rule like this:

```
#list .ui-pg-div.ui-inline-del{}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Your css style is ok, but trash is not in middle, because enveloping div has `margin-left: 8px;` and I didn't find, where it is set. I forgot to say that I use **Oleg's** **jQuery.jqGrid.fontAwesome4.css** and **jQuery.jqGrid.bootstrap-fixes.css** from [link](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins). My actually css from browser inspect `<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="" aria-describedby="table_action">
    <div style="margin-left:8px;">
        <div title="Smazat vybraný záznam " style="fl...
    </div>
</td>`

Comment: If possible create a jsfiddle for your grid. And share here.